# Is there an example where res publica is not republic?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, example-request

The word *res* alone can mean state, and especially *res publica* means that (or republic).
Looking at meanings of *res* and *publicus*, this is not the only possible translation of *res publica*, if no context is given.
Is there an example of *res publica* not referring to the state in classical literature?

For example, it sounds possible to say about different forms of violence within family: *Vexatio est res privata, caedes est res publica.* "Harassing is a private thing, murder a public thing."
I would like to see examples of *res publica* meaning "public thing" in a way like this.
I have been unable to locate any.

This question was inspired by [an earlier one about translating *res*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/309/79).

Comment: My guess is that your example sentence is more likely to be rendered *Vexatio est scelus privatum, cædes publicum* or something of the sort rather then using *res*.

Comment: @JoelDerfner, I agree. The example may not be optimal, but I hope it gets my point across. If you have good artificial examples, I would be happy to add them. (Attested examples, if any, belong to answers.)

Comment: Ah, yes, it definitely gets your point across! I didn't mean to be critical—I was intending more to muse.

Comment: I'm pretty sure res publica also applies to a wider range of related meanings such as politics, public welfare, etc. in Ecclesiastical Latin. I'll do some research. Would that be what you are looking for?

Comment: Here you are! [_Rerum Novarum_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_15051891_rerum-novarum.html), 8: saying that there's no opposition between private ownership and _public goods_ (given by God to the whole human race): _Neque est, cur providentia introducatur reipublicae: est enim homo, quam respublica, senior_. Note that it is written as one word, even when declined as two. The expression _respublica, reipublicae_ is repeated several times along the document.

Comment: @Rafael, I'm not sure that qualifies. (1) I was looking for classical examples, although later ones are interesting as well. (2) Spelling *respublica* together indicates (to me at least) that it not meant as the adjective *publica* modifying the noun *res*, but something more special. (3) It is not clear to me that something other than "state" is meant in the text you cite. (4) I was looking for something more like "public thing" than "society" or "public welfare".

Comment: Hmm, I think in that case the issue becomes a little more slippery. If one sticks strictly to the scheptic's role, it is even difficult to imagine an example in English where any confrontation between private and public stuff cannot be interpreted as confrontation between private stuff and the state w/o asking the writer's intention. FWIW, official translations or _Rerum Novarum_ do not use _republic_ or _state_ to translate every occurrence of _respublica_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dres) (see meaning K), *res publica*, also written as one word (*respublica, reipublicae*), has a wide range of meanings, not limited to *Republic*:

> Res publica, also as one word, respublica, the common weal, a commonwealth, state, republic (cf. civitas); also, civil affairs, administration, or power, etc.

It cites several examples of *res publica* confronted to *res privata*, although a scheptic could still argue that the confrontation may well be between private affairs and the Republic (I think). In my opinion, one clear example is:

> Si re publica non possis frui, stultum est nolle privata (Cic. Fam. 4, 9, 4)

The term is also used in Ecclesiastical Latin to mean things other than the Republic (either the form of government or in the -arguably different- wider Roman sense), e.g. several times in Rerum Novarum to refer to public goods/or affairs. One such example is:

> Neque est, cur providentia introducatur reipublicae: est enim homo, quam respublica, senior (RN, 8)

(this is said in the context that the fact that God has given the world to the whole human race does not rule out private property).

Comment: That quote from Cicero is close to what I was after. The translations in your first blockquote are not; I wanted something much closer to "public thing" than "society", "state", "administration" or the like. (I had difficulties articulating this clearly in my question.) This is a very useful answer.