# A latin word for "area of interest"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

Looking for a word that expresses "Area of Interest", "Sphere of Interest" basically a word that expresses everything a person may be interested in.
Google translate says "Rem" means interest, but translating "rem" back to English says "business". Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for a good question! I appreciate accepting my answer, but please also remember to vote up all answers (not just to this question!) you find useful. The suggestion by luchonacho is a good one.

Comment: When you say "word", do you really mean one word, and not an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me comment on the translation offered by Google Translate.
*Rem* is an accusative form of *res*.
Unless there is more context, I would recommend using the nominative.

The noun *res* is perhaps the broadest noun in Latin.
It can be reasonably translated as "interest" or "business" in a suitable context, but the basic translation is often given as "thing".
I might even give the rule of thumb that when you need a Latin noun and don't know which one would be appropriate, use *res*.

See a [dictionary entry for *res*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=res&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) to get an impression of its breadth.
(There are [a number of online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) to choose from.)
These are the translations the linked entry gives:
thing, object, being, matter, affair, event, fact, circumstance, occurrence, deed, condition, case, something, reality, truth, effects, substance, property, possessions, benefit, profit, advantage, interest, weal, cause, reason, ground, account, business, case, lawsuit, cause, suit, battle, campaign, military operation, act, state, republic, civil affairs, administration, power, political changes, revolution.

Here is an example where *res* would stand for "area of interest":

> – Mea interest lingua Latina. Et tua?
>   (I am interested in Latin. How about you?)
>   – Res meae sunt historia et musica.
>   (My areas of interest are history and music.)

The bottom line is that ***res* (which looks the same in singular and plural) can be used for "area of interest" and is idiomatic**, but on its own it would not be understood as "area of interest" without proper context.
You could say *res meae* to mean "my area of interest" just like the literal translation "my things" can mean it.
The Latin *res* is more formal than the English "thing(s)".
If you want something unambiguous, you will need something else.

It might also be worthwhile to look at [this question about the meaning of *rem*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/309/79).

Comment: Do you mean _res_ alone can be understood as "area of interest"? Can you think of a context/expression/idiom where such is the case?

Comment: @luchonacho I added an example. *Res* is pretty broad. You can use it to refer to just about anything like the English "thing", but *res* feels more formal than the English counterpart.

Answer (score 4):

One option could be

> *materia curiositatis*

*[Materia](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=materia)* is "subject, argument, course of thought, topic", whereas *[curiositatis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curiositas)* is the genitive of *curiositas*, curiosity. So, the above would be "topic of curiosity". *Res curiositatis* is probably also fine, but *res* seems to be much broader than *materia*. Finally, *area*, although [a Latin word itself](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/area#Latin) (and the origin of the English one, it seems), did not have the equivalent English meaning intended in the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is *studium*, which would denote more keenly felt interest than a general word such as *res* – one's area of particular interest, one's pet interest, or one's passion. Definition 3 in the *Oxford Latin dictionary* is:

> That which forms the object of one's interest or energy, an aim or concern

For example, in book 14 of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*, orchard trees are Pomona's area of special interest:

> rege sub hoc Pomona fuit, qua nulla Latinas
>   inter hamadryadas coluit sollertius hortos
>   nec fuit arborei studiosior altera fetus;
>   unde tenet nomen: non silvas illa nec amnes,
>   rus amat et ramos felicia poma ferentes;
>   nec iaculo gravis est, sed adunca dextera falce,
>   qua modo luxuriem premit et spatiantia passim
>   bracchia conpescit, fisso modo cortice virgam
>   inserit et sucos alieno praestat alumno;
>   nec sentire sitim patitur bibulaeque recurvas
>   radicis fibras labentibus inrigat undis.
>   hic amor, **hoc studium**, Veneris quoque nulla cupido est;
>   vim tamen agrestum metuens pomaria claudit
>   intus et accessus prohibet refugitque viriles.

(Lines 623–636)

> Pomona lived in good king Proca's reign
>   And none of all the Latin woodland-nymphs
>   Was cleverer than she in garden lore
>   Nor keener in the care of orchard trees.
>   Thence came her name. For in her heart she loved
>   Not woods nor rivers, but a plot of ground
>   And boughs of smiling apples all around.
>   She had no spear, only a pruning-knife
>   To check too greedy growth and trim to shape
>   The spreading shoots, or slit the bark and set
>   A slip for sap to feed a foreign stock.
>   She never let them thirst; her trickling rills
>   Watered the twisting fibres of their roots.
>   This was her love, **her passion**. Venus' charms
>   Meant nothing; yet for fear of rustic force
>   She walled her orchard in to keep away
>   The sex she shunned.

(Trans. A.D. Melville)

Answer (score 2):

Charles Burnett *[De Eodem et Diverso](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/literature/anglo-saxon-and-medieval-literature/adelard-bath-conversations-his-nephew-same-and-different-questions-natural-science-and-birds?format=PB)* introduction, writes,

> The contrast between *res,* the perceptible realities with which Philocosmia deals, and *verba,* the mental concepts of Philosophia, runs through the whole work.

The five serving girls attending Philocosmia in Adelard are drawn from *Boethius,* [III prose 2 Consolation](https://archive.org/details/CSEL67/page/n77):

> *Habes igitur ante oculos propositam fere formam felicitatis humane: **opes, honores, potentiam, gloriam, voluptates,***
>   ...the epitome of human happiness: wealth, honours, power, fame, pleasures.

So if your interest is one of these, and why not? then the translation is ***res.***

But if your interest has more in common with the seven attendants of Philosophia:
**grammar, rhetoric [eloquence], dialectic; arithmetic, music, geometry, astronomy** then choose (quotations from *De Eodem Et Diverso,' last three paragraphs)
*artes, artium, artibus*

> *studiosius singulis artibus animum applicavi.*
>   I put my mind more intensely to the areas of interest one by one.

*lectio, lectionis, lectione.*

> *eum asserentem audivi, lectiones [scilicet   disciplinares earumque labores] penitentiam non*
>   I heard him insisting that the areas of interest [particularly the discipline and hard work] were not a matter of regret.